# Xamarin Android: Loop thru all item of recyclerview to change colors of all items

Tags: xamarin.android

Hello Everyone my name is Taniguchi

I've made a recyclerview and inserted in it a contextual action mode, when i select a row the contextual action mode is show and none of the items is selected the contextual action mode finishes.

I was having a issue because when i clicked on the back button of the contextual action mode while there were items selected the items stayed selected.

I could solve this problem but i have a code to when i select a item the color of this item changes. Now when i click on the back button of the contextual action mode all the item become unselect but they stay colored.

I wish to loop thrue all the items of the recyclerview and make them transparent. i know the only way to do that is by the OnBindViewHolder, but when i call the method  OnBindViewHolder in the removeSelection is show me an error.

My contextual action mode:

```
public class MyActionMode : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private int currentPosition;
    private Button button;
    public View mView;
    private IMenu menu;
    private View menuItemView;
    private List<Email> mEmails;

    public MyActionMode(Activity mActivity, Context context)
    {

    }

    public MyActionMode(Context context, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, int position, View v, List<Email> Emails)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mAdapter = adapter;
        currentPosition = position;
        mView = v;
        mEmails = Emails;
    }


    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.itemOneId:
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.itemTwoId:
                // do Update
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);
        //------------------------------------------

        button = (Button)menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.itemTwoId).ActionView;
        button.Background = null;
        var draw = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mContext, Resource.Drawable.three_dots);
        button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(draw, null, null, null);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(mContext, button);
            menu1.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
            menu1.Show();
        };

        return true;
    }


    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
        mAdapter.removeSelection(mView, currentPosition);
        mode.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
{
    private View view;
    private Boolean isSelected = false;

    public Boolean IsSelected()
    {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
    {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    private int viewType;
    private ViewGroup parent;
    public static bool unselect = false;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private MyActionMode mActionMode;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    private List<Email> mEmails;
    private Context context;
    private View p;
    private ActionMode mode;
    public static bool count = false;
    public static int CountAuxiliar = 0;
    private MyActionMode myActionMode;

    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Context context)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> mEmails, MyActionMode myActionMode)
    {
        this.mEmails = mEmails;
        this.myActionMode = myActionMode;
    }

    public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View mMainView { get; set; }
        public TextView mName { get; set; }
        public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
        public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

        public MyView(View view) : base(view)
        {
            mMainView = view;
        }

    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mEmails.Count; }
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
        View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
        return vh;
    }
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

            RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
            //myHolder.cbx.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
            //myHolder.cbx.Checked = mEmails[position].IsSelected();


            myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
            myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[position].Subject;
            myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[position].Message;


            //myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            myHolder.ItemView.Tag = position;
            myHolder.ItemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
            myHolder.ItemView.SetOnLongClickListener(this);

    }

    void View.IOnClickListener.OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (CountAuxiliar > 0 && mode != null)
        {
            int position = (int)v.Tag;
            mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
            v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
            if (mEmails[position].IsSelected())
            {
                CountAuxiliar++;
            }
            else
            {
                CountAuxiliar--;
            }
            mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionados";
            Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Click : " + CountAuxiliar + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        if (CountAuxiliar < 1 && count == true)
        {
            count = false;
            mode.Finish();
            MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }
    public void removeSelection(View v,int position)
    {
        if (mEmails != null)
        {
            foreach (Email email in mEmails)
            {
                email.setSelected(false);
            }
            OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);

        }
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public bool OnLongClick(View v)
    {

        if (CountAuxiliar < 1)
        {
            CountAuxiliar = 1;
            count = true;
            int position = (int)v.Tag;
            mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
            v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
            mActionMode = new MyActionMode(mActivity, this, position, v, mEmails);
            mode = mActivity.StartActionMode(mActionMode);
            mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionado";
            count = true;

            Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Long Click : " + mEmails[position].IsSelected() + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When i call OnBindViewHolder on my removeSelection class, it appears this error on OnBindViewHolder class:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for asnwering @CherryBu

I was able to solve this problem by using part of your code:

On the recyclerAdapter i ve created a method called removeSelection:

```
public void removeSelection()
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (mEmails != null)
        {
            foreach (Email email in mEmails)
            {
                email.setSelected(false);

            }
        }
        MyActionMode.mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        CountAuxiliar = 0;
        count = false;
        MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

    }
```

The Line:

```
MyActionMode.mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

will bind the recyclerview again going to OnBindViewHolder method.
and on OnBindViewHolder method have:

```
myHolder.cbx.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
```

The method removeSelection is called on ondestroyactionmode on contextual action mode class:

```
 public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
        mAdapter.removeSelection();
        mode.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to loop thrue all the items of the recyclerview and make them transparent. i know the only way to do that is by the OnBindViewHolder, but when i call the method OnBindViewHolder in the removeSelection is show me an error.

According to your description, you select item from recyclerview, not you want to unselect this item whe you click back button, am I right?
If yes, I suggest you can delect this line in removeSelection method.

```
OnBindviewHolder(holder,position)
```

And don't comment out this line in OnBindViewHolder method.

```
myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
```

Comment: I wish to when i click on  contextual action mode back button, i want to unselect all the items that are selected, hide all the checkboxes and set the background color of all items on the recyclerview to transparent.

Comment: i tool the comment but when i click on the back button it doesnt happen anything